# ajv schema validation fails when working with array types

Tags: json, validation, schema, ajv

I'm using ajv to validate a JSON instance using a fairly simple schema, but that is failing on the `array` type with the following message:

**"this must be equal to one of the allowed values"**

Problem is, my value *is* one of the allowed values. This seems like such a simple problem but I've not yet found a solution. Here's my code:

```
const Ajv = require("ajv");
const ajv = new Ajv();

const schema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    count: { type: "integer" },
    name: { type: "string" },
    bass: {
      type: "array",
      items: {
        type: "string",
      },
      enum: ["Ambush Custom Bass", "MTD", "Ken Smith", "Sadowsky"],
    },
  },
  required: ["count"],
};

const validate = ajv.compile(schema);

const data = {
  count: 1,
  name: "Andy",
  bass: ["MTD"],
};

const valid = validate(data);

console.log("valid: ", valid);

if (!valid) console.log(validate.errors);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

there is actually a much simpler solution: add the `enum` values under `items` field:

```
...
const schema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    count: { type: "integer" },
    name: { type: "string" },
    bass: {
      type: "array",
      items: {
        type: "string",
        enum: ["Ambush Custom Bass", "MTD", "Ken Smith", "Sadowsky"],
      },
    },
  },
  required: ["count"],
};
...
```

This way you don't need to remove/add enum keyword

Answer (score 0):

Well, as usual, I had to first ask the question to the masses so I could figure it out on my own. I don't know if it's the *right* way, but here's what I did:

First, remove the keyword for `enum`, like so:

```
ajv.removeKeyword("enum");
```

Next, add the `enum` keyword back, and with it, your custom validation function:

```
ajv.addKeyword({
  keyword: "enum",
  validate: (schema, data, value, other) => {
    // custom validation goes here
  }
});
```

Finally, I found that the `validate` function here doesn't give you the option of adding detailed error messaging (or, if it does, I couldn't figure out how to do it), so I created an error array, then pushed entries into that array, with each entry being an object that includes `other.instancePath`. Then when iterating through the `validation.errors` array, I combine the more detailed messaging with ajv's errors so I can have custom error messaging along with the error details ajv provides. I hope that makes sense; if not, give me a holler, and I'll further explain.